# Почему при парсинге питон выводит []?

Tags: python, парсер

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
url = 'https://youla.ru/leninogorsk/smartfony-planshety'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='sc-hgqobU laTgWi')
print(items)
for n, i in enumerate(items, start=1):
    itemname = i.find('span', class_='sc-cOajty sc-fwaKix jMbTCK gCzrcm').text.strip()
    itemprice = i.find('span', class_='sc-dYdMoy hvzGDz').text
    print(f'{n}:  {itemprice} за {itemname}')
```

Выводиться [], но почему, я вроде правильно указал класс объекта, которую спарсить.
Подскажите что делать, только учусь парсить.

Comment: По указанной вами ссылке не существует элемента с таким классом. Вероятно, он добавляется скриптом уже после загрузки страницы

Comment: И вообще зачем вам парсить html, если на странице в `window.__YOULA_STATE__` лежит готовенький машиночитаемый json-объект

Comment: @Karasmhi видимо, элемент подгружается динамически. ты можешь добавить time.sleep(), чтобы элемент прогрузился, и уже потом его спарсить

Comment: @headswillroll c requests такое не прокатит. Потому что requests это вам не selenium.

Comment: @СергейШ ты прав, что-то я забыл про это. ну, в общем, если динамически что-то генерится, то юзай селениум с time.sleep